# I want to show a multiple circle on image view particular coordinates

Tags: android

I want to show  a multiple  circle on image view  particular coordinates and  when a click on that circle it will retrturn info about that circle coordinates and show 2 button 
is that possible in android 
if possible then give me a suggestion for how to set click event that circle

Comment: You can not ask directly for code here. You need to show your effort and SO help to solve errors.

Comment: iam try im draw a cirlc on image using canvas draw but i cant understant how to set click event on that circle

Comment: Not directly draw. Use CustomView for that.

Comment: i m new in android if u know please help me

Comment: check [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) about CustomView.

Comment: @SAGAR ADKHALE use `onTouchEvent`

Comment: hello sir how to set minimum height of image view

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set an `onClick` event for a drawn circle.

You should set the `onClick` event to your `ImageView` object. Better, set an `onTouch` event. Then, save all circles in a list with their coordinates.

In the `onTouch` listener make a search on your list to test if your click is inside the circle.

```
imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            float downx = event.getX();
            float downy = event.getY();
            // downx, downy => coordinates for click
            // with these coordinates you can search in you list to find the circle
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry sir im ittle bit confuse  here how to use list

Comment: @SAGARADKHALE Please, share how you are drawing your circles.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ConstraintLayout to show any type of view anywhere and get click event of that view:)